# linux: generate a key sequence with shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autocomplete, xkb

I want to generate a key sequence `(`+`)`+`left` when pressing `(` (actually it is `Shift+9`), so that I can achieve autocomplete of bracket globally. Is there any way to do this?

Implementation with `xkb` is preferred, because it is more fundamental (and I do not think the kernel itself can do this for me). Other high-level implementation is also welcomed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom xkb layout in which one key creates two unicode code points](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43073/custom-xkb-layout-in-which-one-key-creates-two-unicode-code-points)

Comment: @l0b0 Thanks, but that answer does not solve my question. Even the answerer himself does not verified the answer.