# Make xkb produce two symbols on one key press (e.g. make `ctrl`+`+` & `ctrl`+`=` produce same (combined) effect to get rid of `Shift` for zooming in)

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xkb, keyboard-event

Some apps use `ctrl`+`+` and some `ctrl`+`=` to zoom in. Only some allow to customize. If all used same, I would just remap the keyboard not to use `Shift`. Can I make apps receive signals that both combinations are pressed when I press one of them?

I've tried web search for key generation and found QAs on bash solutions and that one advising writing `c` code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262777/how-to-simulate-keyboard-key-press-code-ascii-of-alt-key. I know key bindings can be edited in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` and I can switch `+` and `=` as reaction to `Shift`. I realized I do not understand how the system processes `Ctrl` press as I have found neither `ctrl` not `control` in e.g. `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`. Maybe the easy way to make my idea work is somewhere else...

Added:

I've found [Custom xkb layout in which one key creates two unicode code points](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43073/custom-xkb-layout-in-which-one-key-creates-two-unicode-code-points) where answer proposes some workaround with comment "I dug through the source code, there doesn't seem to be any support for including multiple keystrokes in the key definitions of the keymap.", but it was in **2012**, maybe now it is possible easier.